# Setting limits over and under the integrals in an entire group

Tags: math-mode

Is there a command to print the integration limits over and under the integral symbols in an entire group / the entire document without writing `\int\limits` every time? That is, i'd like to be able to write

```
{\mysterycommand
    \int_a^b (f + g) = \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g
}
```

instead of

```
\int\limits_a^b (f + g) = \int\limits_a^b f + \int\limits_a^b g
```

Comment: `\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}`?

Comment: You could create you own macro.  Using \let\oldint=\int you could even name it \int and use \oldint for the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `amsmath` it's easy to get *all* integrals with limits above and below (which I wouldn't recommend, though):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_a^b (f + g) = \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your `\misterycommand` can be defined easily:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mysterycommand{\let\ilimits@\displaylimits}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

No limits:
\[
\int_a^b (f + g) = \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g
\]
Limits:
\[\mysterycommand
\int_a^b (f + g) = \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now that you see the result, I hope you understand why limits are usually set on the side.

Comment: Isn't there a differential missing? Or is this a strange mathematical notation I am not aware of? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In this case the differential is not necessary; a formula that just illustrates a property. Abuse of notation is very common.

Comment: I graded a lot of German Abitur - exams during the  last two days and I got angry about so much missing differential symbols ;-)